# RequestFactory IllegalArgumentException:property

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I create a proxy from a clean request, and then set some properties. It works for some of them but for the others, I get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
    MyRequest myRequest = myRequestProvider.get();
    MyProxy my = myRequest.create(MyProxy.class);
    my.setPaypal("xxx");
```

and I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: paypal` in `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire()`.

Comment: Please post the stack trace - the event bus likely is catching the exception fired from another source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proxy class did not define a getter for the property `paypal`. By adding the getter the exception is gone. Hope it helps.